# Stackoverflow like error display

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, stack-overflow

see this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h76jg/)

What i have is few `button` and `div` of same class.
When i click a `button` of a **class** the `div` of **same class** gets `scrollIntoView` and the `.log` appears beside the div on  its *right* side.

***PROBLEMS***

1. OnClick button the scroll does not happen
2. The `.log` does not appear beside `div`
3. The small triangle pointer does not appear beside `.log`

***Additions***(The thing i want but dont know how do i do it!)

1. Whenever the `.log` appears i want it to shake little `up`and `down`
   which continues to do untill `mouseover`
2. After `mouseout` i want the `.log` to `fadeOut(2000)`

**FOR downvoters**

```
<button class="a1">Div1</button>
<button class="a2">Div2</button>
<button class="a3">Div3</button>
<button class="a4">Div4</button>
<button class="a5">Div5</button>
<button class="a6">Div6</button>
<div id="container">
    <div class="a1">This is div1</div>
    <div class="a2">This is div2</div>
    <div class="a3">This is div3</div>
    <div class="a4">This is div4</div>
    <div class="a5">This is div5</div>
</div>
<div class="log">Your have a fatal error.</div>


#container div {
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    margin:15px;
}
#container {
    margin:20px;
}
.log {
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #c04848;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    max-width:270px;
    font-size:15px;
    padding:10px;
    position: absolute;

}
.log:after {
    top: 0;
    left: -9px;
    border-top: 9px solid #c04848;
    border-left: 9px solid transparent;
}


    $('button').click(function(){
             var c =  $(this).attr('class');
             var div = $('#container div.'+c);     
        $(document).scrollTo(div, 1000);
        log.css({
            top : div.position().top + div.height()/2,
            left : div.position().left + 20
        }).show();
    });
```

Comment: Please paste the code to the question itself. A jsfiddle is good but not enough by itself.

Comment: `scrollTo` is a jQuery plugin - http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=scrollto

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it

```
$('button').click(function(){
         var c =  $(this).attr('class');
         var div = $('#container div.'+c);     
    $(document).scrollTop(div.offset().top);
    $('.log').css({
        top : div.position().top + div.height()/2,
        left : div.position().left + 20
    }).show();
});
```

What I did is changed the `scrollTo` to `scrollTop`. I have added a selector to log class because most likely you forgot it.

### Shaky effect

```
var inter;
function bounceOn(){
    var pos = $('.log').position().left;
    $('.log').animate({left: pos+50},500, function(){$('.log').animate({left: pos},500)})
    setTimeout(bounceOn, 1000);
}
```

Try and make something out it maybe?

http://jsfiddle.net/h76jg/6/

Comment: but what about shaky `.log` ?

Comment: the `.log` after `.show()` should animate continuously left and right or back and forth until its `mouseover`ed like one done in stackoverflow while asking a question ! @dharman

Comment: @HackerManiac what do you mean "Yeah sure done.."? Are you unhappy with the answer after 1.5 years?

Comment: No I was watching porn just when my Mom appeared so i just opened this and commented it was quick but logicless so nevermind

Answer (score 2):

All parts of my answer are shown in this [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h76jg/4/)

In terms of scrollTo, you were probably looking for scrollTop. Try something like this:

```
scrollTop: div.offset().top
```

instead of:

```
$(document).scrollTo(div, 1000);
```

Although, Just going by what your writing there, I am going to assume you wanted some sort of smooth transition to the div, correct? Try this instead:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: div.offset().top
}, 1000);
```

This will create a smooth scroll to the div instead of just moving to it.

For the log section, you forgot to reference the log class. Instead, you tried to reference it like a variable, so the interpreter got confused. Try putting the log css call in a reference, like this:

```
$('.log').css({...
```

Hope these help!

Edit: Were you intending something like [This](http://jsfiddle.net/h76jg/9/) for the bounce? (up and down?). Either Case, @Dharman has the right idea with his code. You would just want to add another animation (similar to the scrolling), but put a timeout on the end (so the method will continually repeat)

Comment: but what about shaky `.log` ?

Comment: Have a look at my edit, and let me know if that's what you were intending

Answer (score 1):

Since i cannot accept anyone's answer coz i dont like em but thanks for an idea of `bounce` animation that did worked... 
now i have created my own [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/h76jg/11/) And it worked perfetly!

```
$('button').click(function () {
    var c = $(this).attr('class');
    var div = $('div.' + c);
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: div.offset().top
    }, 1000); //thanks to Dylan Corriveau
    console.log(div.position().left);
    $('.log').css({
        top: div.position().top + div.height() / 2,
        left: div.position().left + div.width() + 50
    }).show();
    clearTimeout(inter);
    setTimeout(bounceOn, 500);

});

$('.log').mouseover(function () {
    clearTimeout(inter);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(3500);
});

var inter;
//here is the magic!
function bounceOn() {
    var pos = $('.log').position().left;
    $('.log').animate({
        left: pos + 15
    }, 50, function () {
        $('.log').animate({
            left: pos
        }, 50)
    })
    inter = setTimeout(bounceOn, 215);
}
```